# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure what I'm overlooking here:

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)) in the line where the ActionCable is executed

Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @message.save  
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel_#{@message.room_id}", message: "hello"
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
  else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Rails 6.1.3.2
ruby 3.0.1p64

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's expecting an actual argument, not a keyword arg in the second place? [The code you wrote passes (with a warning) on Ruby 2.7 but no longer works on Ruby 3.](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/)

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "room_channel_#{@message.room_id}", { message: "hello" }
```

Comment: It takes two positional arguments. `broadcast(broadcasting, message, coder: ActiveSupport::JSON)` https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActionCable/Server/Broadcasting.html#method-i-broadcast

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41050/files this is the exact solution of this.